# Deleting certain rows from a data frame

Tags: r, random, dataframe, regression

The data is confidential so here is a dummy data frame for example.

```
  i1  i2 o1
1 72 3.1 69
2 12 1.1 46
3 16 2.0 37
4 16 7.9 70
5 24 7.0 27
6 12 9.9 49
```

I want to divide this data frame into 3 data frames of fixed sizes but the rows must be selected without replacement. here, say I select a random part of it using :-

```
x=sample(6,3);
df_part1=df[x,]
```

The rows selected at random are :-

```
  i1  i2  o1
4 16  2.0  37
6 12  9.9  49 
1 72  3.1  69
```

Now, before I select the 2nd part, I want to delete these specific rows from the data frame. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want to `split` your dataframe, not delete rows from it. If the dataframes are of equal sizes and you want the three extracted dataframes to be random samples, specify something like:

```
split(df, sample(1:3,dim(df)[1],TRUE))
```

to get a list of the three sampled, mutually exclusive dataframes. No need to delete anything from the original dataframe.

Also, if you want to have the dataframes have different sizes, you can specify a `prob` argument in `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

You could sample `1:6` first and then extract the information from the shuffled 6 numbers:

```
tmp <- sample(6, 6)
```

`tmp[1:3], tmp[4:6]` will give you the information, and you could go from there. I hope this helps.